# Count cells that contain certain letters (Visual Basic)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a function in VBA that will count the cells that contain certain letters in a specific range. My code so far is

```
Function letters(list As range) As Double

    Dim limit As Integer
    limit = UBound(list.Value)

    Dim total As Double
    total = 0

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To limit
        If range(list).Offset(i, 2) = "PD" Then
        total = total + 1
        End If
    Next i

    letters = total

End Function
```

So my input is =letters(A1:B6) and lets say B2, B3, and B5 have the text "PD". I expect my answer to be 3 but I get a #value! error. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Few suggestions, `limit = list.Rows.Count`  ,  `if list(i, 2) = "PD" Then`. list(i, 2) will loop through the cells in each row in the second column, if thats what you want

Comment: Very easy solution. `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A25"), "PD")`

Comment: Even easier will be to use COUNTIF directly in the sheet. No need to write a custom function. I feel the OP wants to match the text anywhere in the cell content

Comment: nightcrawler23 @barney your answers make sense. I guess the next thing for me is I'd like to know why I'm getting the #value! error. I want to know what is it about my lines of code that give me the error so that I further my understanding of data types and such.

Comment: Side note: Don't use a `Double` variable if it only deals with whole numbers. You can use `Integer` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each cell in the range and use INSTR to find if the cell contains the text. Increment a counter if it does and then output it.

```
Function findText(myRange As Range, toFind As String)
    Dim ra As Range
    Dim rCount As Integer
    rCount = 0


    For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        If InStr(1, myRange(i, 1), toFind, vbTextCompare) Then
            rCount = rCount + 1
        End If
    Next i

    findText = rCount

End Function
```

This will count event those cells which have the required text anywhere in the cell. If you want to match the whole cell contents, just use

```
If myRange(i, 1) = toFind Then
```

Also, the function works for a range in single column.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question

> Where am I going wrong?

there are some points to be addressed:

- you say you call your function with

  ```
   =letters(A1:B6)
  ```

  but `A1:B6` doesn't mean anything, while you have two options:

  - either you call your function passing a literal `string` as a valid `Range` address

    `=letters("A1:B6")`
  - or you call it passing a `Range` object directly

    `=letters(Range("A1:B6"))`
- once you're done with the previous point you must act consistently, i.e.:

  - option 1: passing a literal `string` as a valid `Range` address

    then `"A1:B6"` (notice the double quotes surrounding `A2:B6`) is the address of your range so you have to:

    - change:

      ```
      limit = UBound(list.Value) '<--| error
      ```

      a `string` doesn't have a `Value` property

      to:

      ```
      limit = UBound(Range(list).Value) '<--| OK
      ```

      `Range("A1:B6")` is a valid `Range` reference so you can access its `Value` property
    - change:

      ```
      Range(list).Offset(i, 2) '<--| this references a range as large as the one it's being called upon!
      ```

      `Offset(nRows, nColumns)` method will reference a range that's "shifted" from the one it's being called upon by as many rows and columns as you put in its parameters. So `Offset(i,2)` called upon `Range("A1:B6")` references `Range("C2:D7")` when `i`=1, `Range("C3:D8")` when `i`=2 and so on

      to:

      ```
      Range(list).Cells(i, 2) '<--| it references a single cell
      ```

      `Cells(iRow, iColumn)` method will reference the cell in the `iRow`th row and `iColumn`th column of the `Range` it's being called upon. So `Range("A1:B6").Cells(1,2)` references cell "B7"
  - option 2: passing a `Range` object

    since `list` is already a `Range` object (namely `Range("A1:B6")`), you have to:

    - change:

      ```
      If Range(list).Offset(i, 2) = "PD" Then '<--| error
      ```

      you cannot pass a `Range` object as the only argument of another `Range` object

    to:

    ```
        If list.Cells(i, 2) = "PD" Then '<--| Ok
    ```

    where you use `Cells` property of `Range` object as already discussed in option 1
- then you may want to consider the following *miscellanea*:

  - declare your `Function` as of `Long` type

    since:

    - you're returning an integer value, so there's no need to use a `Double` type
    - the number of row can exceed some 65 k limit of an `Integer` type variable
  - declare `Dim limit As Long`

    since with

    ```
     limit = UBound(Range(list).Value) '<--| correct use of 'list' if it's a literal 'string'
    ```

    you're assigning it the actual number of rows of a Range and it could exceed the some 65k limit of an `Integer` type variable

---

all that said, I think the most effective VBA solution would be using [WorksheetFunction.CountIF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx) function as follows:

```
Function letters(list As String) As Long
    letters = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(list).Columns(2), "PD")
End Sub
```

where you'd use `.Columns(n)` property of `Range` object to reference the nth column of the `Range` it's being called upon

and which you could make more general by expanding its arguments list to the searched string

```
Function letters(list As String, myLetters As String) As Long
    letters = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(list).Columns(2), myLetters)
End Sub
```

that you'd call like:

```
MsgBox letters("A1:B6", "PD")
```

Comment: @Soto, did you get through it?

Comment: Your solution makes sense but I didn't try all the suggestions. I came up with a tested solution.

Comment: Your solution makes sense but I didn't try all the suggestions. I came up with a tested solution. My apologies. Do I post my answer in this comment? Or do I answer my own question. Do I also accept your answer? Not sure what the norm is here. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: well, you posted your code and made a question _"Where am I going wrong?"_ If there's a an answer that satisfies such a request you should mark it as accepted. I saw there's an already marked answer: if that's the answer you think best matches your request than leave it as such. Otherwise change. Besides all that you can still post an answer with the code you came up. You can take a look at [this relevant help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for a more complete oversight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can achieve this just by using the below formula instead of using VBA.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(FIND("PD",A1:A25,1)>0,FALSE)))
```

You need to enter this as an array Formula i.e. Enter the formula and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`FIND("PD",A1:A25,1)` gives you the text position or an error if text is not found for each cell.

`>0` converts the number to TRUE. If it an error `IFERROR` converts it to FALSE. Hence you get an array of `TRUEs` and `FALSEs`  like `{TRUE,FALSE,...}`

The `--({...})` converts the array to 1s and 0s. 1 for `TRUE` and 0 for `FALSE`. `SUMPRODUCT` adds this numeric array to give you the count.